# How to break out of recursion at a base case in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that computes all the [weird numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeirdNumber.html) up to a given integer. To determine if a number n is pseudoperfect, I was trying to come up with a better solution than naively computing the sum of every combination of divisors until I either exhaust all the combinations or find a solution. I ended up with the idea that you can recursively reduce the problem by definitely proving inclusion of certain divisors in the sum. Take 12 for example: you know that 6 *must* be included in the final sum because the total of all other divisors is less than 12. Then the problem is reduced to summing to the rest of 12 (ie 12 - 6, ie 6) from the remaining divisors, and so forth. If you reach 0, then the number is pseudoperfect. If you exhaust all the divisors then it's not pseudoperfect.

Here's my code so far:

(The functions `powerset` and `divisors` do the expected: return a list of all sublists, and a list of divisors respectively. Obviously RETURN is just a placeholder for I want to do.)

```
pseudoperfect _ 0 = RETURN True
pseudoperfect d n =
   let g = zipWith (\x y -> x) d (filter (< 0) (map (subtract n) (scanl1 (+) d))) in
   map (\x -> pseudoperfect g (n - (sum x))) (filter (not . null) (powerset(d \\ g)))

-- Determine if n is weird, ie, abundant and not pseudoperfect.
weird n = ((sum . divisors) (n) > n) && not (pseudoperfect (divisors n) n) 

-- Find weird numbers up to given n.
weirds n = filter (weird) [1..n]
```

I tried working through a couple examples on paper and I got the correct result. My problem is that I want to just break out of the recursion and return True when I reach that base case of n = 0. Is there a way to do this in Haskell, or do I need to restructure the function somehow so that I'm passing returned value at the base case value back up through the stack?

Comment: It's actually not the base case that seems problematic -- just let `pseudoperfect _ 0 = True` -- it's the recursive case.  Right now, it looks like the types don't match up because the recursive case produces a list (of recursive results) rather than a bool.  Based on your description, it looks like you want this case to be `True` so long as _any_ of that list is `True`.  With that in mind, maybe you want to use the`any` function on that list instead of `map` (or `or` the result of the `map`).

Comment: What's the purpose of `zipWith (\x y -> x)`? That's basically just going to return the first list unchanged.

Comment: @chepner `zipWith const xs ys` is a common idiom for a lazier version of `take (length ys) xs`.

Comment: @DDub The `any` function was exactly was I was looking for, thank you!